# jquery textarea validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

How to check for null,white spaces and new lines while validating for a textarea using jquery.
If the textarea is empty and has only new lines or spaces should raise an alert

Answer (score 5):

```
if($.trim($('#myTextArea').val()) == '') {
    //error
}
```

Comment: New line validation doesnt hold good with this code.I had tried this before

Comment: From the API Docs: The $.trim() function removes all newlines, spaces (including non-breaking spaces), and tabs from the beginning and end of the supplied string

Comment: <textarea> is different from <input type='text'> .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming html that looks like

```
<form id='someForm'>
    <input type="text" id='textInput' name='textInput'/>
</form>
```

First create a jquery validation method.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkForWhiteSpaceErrors", function(value, element, param){
    var elem = $(element);
    var val = element.val();
    //Now you have a choice.  Either use trim, or if you believe that 
    //  that is not working, use a regex.
    if(val && $.trim(val) == '') {
        return false;
    }
    //or 
    if(val && val.match(/^\s+|\s+$/g)) {
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}, "Newlines and White Spaces are not allowed.");
```

Now its a simple matter of telling the form validator to use this method.

```
$('#someForm').validate({
    rules: {
        textInput: {
            checkForWhiteSpaceErrors: true
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: <textarea> is different from <input type='text'>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks 'Keith Rousseau'! it worked. 
moreover if you have one text-box and one textarea than below jquery code will be fine:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#message_submit').click(function (e) { //submit button ID
            var isValid = true;
            $('input[type="text"]').each(function () {  //textbox type
                if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '' || $.trim($('#body').val()) == '') { //#body is textarea ID
                    alert('Text box can't left empty');
                    return false;
                }
                else
                    alert('Thanks for your valuable input!\nWe will get back to you soon.');
            });
            });
        });
```

Comment: This adds a lot of extraneous code that doesn't pertain to the original question (or substantially add to your mentioned answer). It also won't run.