# Text area validation?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to validate my  text are while entering data.

I had written code for on `keypress` event.

```
function validateQuestionTextArea(questionid)
{

  var txtbx=$('questions-'+questionid).value;

  if(txtbx.length > 99)
  {
    showValidationMessage('questionMaxLengthValidation');
    return false
  }

  return true

}
```

The problem with this is that I can use <kbd>backspace</kbd> or <kbd>delete</kbd> once it reached the 100.

Which event should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might wanna use KeyUp instead ^^

Comment: using keyUp i can insert more than my limit. if i keep pressing a key and released after 150, keyDown also have prblem like i cant delete or backspace once it reach the maximum length

Comment: on Key Up use substring to delete extra text.

anyways, you can still delete the extra text on the server side, so if you're facing a stubborn user, he'll get just what he diserves (Canceling)

Comment: TAHRI JOUTi : THANK YOU FOR THE HINT . i got using subscript

Answer (score 0):

see jquery way [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577991/jquery-textarea-validation).. or follow below steps

> first get the data then trim from both side
>   then count and compare with max length